# Gulp Watch starts but doesn't compile

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-watch

When compiling my gulp file using "gulp watch", the gulp proces starts but doesn't compile. It isn't outputting any errors, so I'm not sure why it's starting but not compiling any of the files. This is what my gulp file currently looks like:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const stylus = require('gulp-stylus');
const nib = require('nib');
const rupture = require('rupture');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
//const concat = require('gulp-concat');

// compiles styl to css and creates updates source map
gulp.task('styles', function(){
    gulp.src('css/styl/style.styl')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) // <-- place sourcemaps.init before stylus nib pipe so that nib is included in sourcemap
        .pipe(stylus({
            use: [nib(),rupture()]
        }))
        .pipe(postcss([ autoprefixer() ]))
        //.pipe(concat('style.css'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('css/**/*.styl', gulp.series('styles'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is currently written it would compile on changes only, not on startup. What you want is to make your `watch`-task dependent on your `styles` task, so that `styles` is run before it starts watching. You can do this by passing another argument to `gulp.task` like this.

```js
gulp.task('watch', ['styles'] function() {
    gulp.watch('css/**/*.styl', gulp.series('styles'));
});
```